# Saving directory paths in JSON?

Tags: c#, json, wpf, treeview

I have an application that displays a treeview of a folders, with the format below:

```
- Main Folder
    - SubFolder
    - SubFolder
        - SubFolder
    - SubFolder
```

Questions:
1) `How do I search for all the folders (not files) and add them to a List called syncDirectories`**(FIXED)**

2) `How would I then iterate through my JSON object and save it back to List<SavedData> in order to add/remove data` **(FIXED)**

3) `How would I loop through my syncDirectories List and add all the nodes to the TreeView in WPF. (Keep in mind the treeview with checkbox class i am using.`

And so on. Also, this is an example to demonstrate the format, and users could have more subdirectories.

Each of these folders has a checkbox on it thanks to this [TREEVIEW CLASS.](http://www.thebestcsharpprogrammerintheworld.com/blogs/treeview-with-checkbox-in-wpf-using-csharp.aspx)

In order to save all the folders and subfolders the user adds (and checks), I thought saving a JSON file listing all the folder and subfolder paths, along with their (true/false) checked values would be a good idea. Right? I am using Json.NET.

Messing around with some JSON, I came up with this format:

```
{   
    "path": "path/here",
    "subDirectories": [
        {"path": "sub/path/here","sync": false},
        {"path": "sub/path/here","sync": true},
        {"path": "sub/path/here","sync": false}
    ]
}
```

Which translated into the class:

```
public class SavedData
{
    public string path { get; set; }
    public List<SubDirectory> subDirectories { get; set; }
}

public class SubDirectory
{
    public string path { get; set; }
    public bool sync { get; set; }
    public List<SubDirectory> subDirectories { get; set; }
}
```

This raises the question, How do I search for all the folders (not files) and add them to a `List` called `syncDirectories`?

Here is what I have so far in my `addDirectory` function:

```
private void addDirectory()
{
    var dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();
    if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        SavedData data = new SavedData();
        data.path = dialog.SelectedPath;
        syncedDirectories.Add();
    }
    // Add the data to syncedDirectories List, then save the list and refresh the treeView
    saveData();
}
```

And the save function:

```
    public void saveData()
    {
        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(appData))
        using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, syncedDirectories);
        }
    }
```

When I save the data into a file, How would I then iterate through my JSON object and save it back to `List<SavedData>` in order to add/remove data?

**UPDATE 1**

I have figured out how to handle my data (Below), but how exactly would i add these "nodes" to the treeview?

```
    public void getDirectories(string dir)
    {
        // Create the Data Object
        SavedData data = new SavedData();
        data.path = dir;
        data.subDirectories = new List<SubDirectory>();
        foreach (string directory in Directory.GetDirectories(dir))
        {
            SubDirectory subDir = new SubDirectory();
            subDir.path = directory;
            subDir.subDirectories = getSubDir(directory);
            data.subDirectories.Add(subDir);
        }
        syncedDirectories.Add(data);
    }

    private List<SubDirectory> getSubDir(string dir)
    {
        List<SubDirectory> dataList = new List<SubDirectory>();
        SubDirectory subDir = new SubDirectory();
        foreach (string directory in Directory.GetDirectories(dir))
        {
            subDir.path = directory;
            subDir.subDirectories = new List<SubDirectory>();
            subDir.subDirectories = getSubDir(directory);
            dataList.Add(subDir);
        }
        return dataList;
    }
```

Later, i plan to release this program open source on GitHub. When i do, i will post the link here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a couple hours of playing around with a function, I realized two functions are needed to complete this task.

```
    public void getDirectories(string dir)
    {
        // Create the Data Object
        SavedData data = new SavedData();
        data.path = dir;
        data.subDirectories = new List<SubDirectory>();
        foreach (string directory in Directory.GetDirectories(dir))
        {
            SubDirectory subDir = new SubDirectory();
            subDir.path = directory;
            subDir.subDirectories = getSubDir(directory);
            data.subDirectories.Add(subDir);
        }
        syncedDirectories.Add(data);
    }

    private List<SubDirectory> getSubDir(string dir)
    {
        List<SubDirectory> dataList = new List<SubDirectory>();
        SubDirectory subDir = new SubDirectory();
        foreach (string directory in Directory.GetDirectories(dir))
        {
            subDir.path = directory;
            subDir.subDirectories = new List<SubDirectory>();
            subDir.subDirectories = getSubDir(directory);
            dataList.Add(subDir);
        }
        return dataList;
    }
```

This gets the main directory then loops and finds all the subdirectories and adds them to my list.